# mvc4 template for developing mobile web application

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am new to monoDevelop 3.0.4.7 . In that there is no MVC4 template so,any one tell me how to get the template for developing mobile web application ?

Answer (score 1):

While Mono 3.0 now [includes the MVC4 stack](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Oct-22.html), the [release notes](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_3.0.4) for MonoDevelop 3.0.4 only mention support for MVC2 & MVC3.

If you're using MonoDevelop then I'd recommend sticking with MVC3 for the time being.

I've not come across an MVC3 template for MonoDevelop yet so for my last project I created an MVC3 bare bones application in Visual Studio and then made the necessary adjustments to get it to run with MonoDevelop on my Mac.

There are a couple of pages [here](http://blog.yojimbocorp.com/2012/08/27/asp-net-mvc3-with-razor-view-engine-using-monodevelop-and-ubuntu-12-04/) and [here](https://github.com/danielmiladinov/ASP.NET-MVC3-Razor-Mono-Bootstrap) that have useful information for getting an MVC3 application running with MonoDevelop.